# I don't know how to fix this error in the question

Tags: java, flutter

I don't know how to fix this error can you please help me?

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @203e7cb0

I am very grateful for every answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: Your tooling (The code that powers the `processDebugMainManifest` task, which I think is the Android Build System) is trying to do a task in java, but this task is simply not available in public APIs. Instead of accepting that it is impossible to write an Android Build system in java in the way the android team wanted, the devs of android instead realised that JVMs **can** do it, it's just that there is no public accesspoint to ask it to do it. Thus, they decided to use the not-intended-for-public-consumption part, given that without doing this they can't do the job at all, and have accepted the maintenance burden.

Unfortunately, Team OpenJDK is aggressively locking this stuff down, even though usually there is no ready alternative (as in, the right order is obviously to first make an inventory of commonly used private APIs, then make suitable alternatives for the top 95% of usage, and **then** proceed with lockdown, though not in such a heavyhanded fashion as they have chosen to do - team OpenJDK hasn't done this)<sup>1</sup>.

That's what this warning means: The java release you use is no longer 'allowing' it. This java release has broken `processDebugMainManifest` for a dubious reason. Likely whatever pDMM is trying to do is now completely impossible in java releases that locked this down and thus...

**Solution**:

*Downgrade your java.*

Download [AdoptOpenJDK's OpenJDK8](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot) which is free and open source.

In particular when doing android dev this is generally a good idea. Android has never worked well with newer javas; neither the features introduced in the language, nor the additions to the core libs (as android has its own implementation of them). The existence of [this courtcase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_LLC_v._Oracle_America,_Inc.) probably isn't helping things along.

---

[1] I have oversimplified a tad; for example, there are a few methods in `sun.misc.Unsafe` which OpenJDK openly states are sometimes neccessary and they are more or less committed to keeping Unsafe available until they've found adequate alternatives for all such uses (if only they had that attitude for a few more commonly used internal bits, there wouldn't be such a gulf between the community and the openjdk team). Also, there is common 'internal API' usage which is indeed inappropriate, such as the widespread use of `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` which no library/tool/app ever should have used, and for which alternatives have always been available, and these days, alternatives are baked into the JDK itself: Team OpenJDK's decision to effectively eliminate both direct access to BASE64Encoder as well as shutting down all attempts to work around the lack of direct access are therefore probably justified. It's shades of gray: Whenever private API use occurs, part of the blame lies with the OpenJDK for not having an alternative, and part of the blame lies with the library/tool/app for envisioning the way it works in a way that can't be done (easily) without relying on internals that weren't designed for public use like this. My impression is that the core OpenJDK contributors are **wildly** misjudging themselves on this divide and basically placing virtually all blame not on them but on the library builders, and aren't giving sensible solutions other than 'pull your entire tool/library/app from existence, you should never have written it'. Thus, I'm faring on statistics here, but it is quite likely the explanation of whatever's going on here: The OpenJDK is locking down the ability to do this stuff without having a reasonable alternative, therefore `processDebugMainManifest`, even the most recent version, would still cause this error and they can't fix this error without rewriting a ton of code and completely changing how it works for the users of the Android Build infrastructure.

Some insights (including that vibe that OpenJDK core contributors seem to feel the blame lies almost entirely with apps/libraries/tools) is on display on [this Inside Java podcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRX_stwoOgo) with Alan Bateman.